# how can i Call event after scroll controller attached

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

```
@override
  void initState()
 {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController(initialScrollOffset: 0);
    _scrollController.addListener((_scrollControllerInitiated));
}

void _scrollControllerInitiated()
{
_scrollController.jumpto(1000);
}
```

need to call _scrollControllerInitiated method after scroll controller attached

Comment: what will be inside _scrollControllerInitiated?

Comment: need to jump specific offset after scrollcontroller attached

Comment: and what is the issue with the current approach ?

Comment: scrolllistener triggered after i scroll the image only( _scrollControllerInitiated) method called after the scroll the page,i need to call the method immediately  after scrollcontroller attached.

Comment: then add the image code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what `_scrollController.addListener` does is listen to any scroll event and call the registered callback function. If you wall the scroll to jump to a certain offSet after being attached to the ListView or any scrollable widget you should use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` to register a callback function after the widgets have been built. Check the code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyApp createState() => _MyApp();
}

class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  void _scrollControllerInitiated() {
    _scrollController.animateTo(200,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        print("hello $index");
      }),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 15),
        child: Text("Box $index"),
      ),
    );
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _scrollControllerInitiated();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Scroll Test"),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
          itemCount: 200,
          controller: _scrollController,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```dart
void _scrollControllerInitiated() {
  Future(() => _scrollController.jumpTo(1000));
}
```

Comment: it called after , scroll the image only.,i need to call this immediately after scroll controller attached.

Comment: @AllwinVinosh This will get called once the things are laid out (which means your controller has been attached to the ListBody). I'm not using `Future.delayed`, its regular `Future`